# How to make if-else and while condition inside html in php?

Tags: php, laravel

Inside my HTML, I want to make if-else and while loop but something went wrong every attempt. Kindly check what I am doing wrong:

```
  <input type="radio" name="brand" value=""<?=(($brandValue == '')?' checked':'');?>> All<br>
  <?php if ($cat_id != ''): ?>
  <?php while ($brand = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlOnlyCatBrands)) : ?>
  <?php elseif ($cat_id == ''): ?>
  <?php while ($brand = mysqli_fetch_assoc($brandQ)) : ?>

  <?php endif; ?>

   <input type="radio" name="brand" value="<?=$brand['id'];?>"<?= (($brandValue == $brand['id'])?' checked':'');?> > <?=$brand['brand'];?> . 
   <br>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I want if my $cat_id is not blank then execute

```
<?php while ($brand = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlOnlyCatBrands)) : ?>
```

I want if my $cat_id is blank then execute

```
  <?php while ($brand = mysqli_fetch_assoc($brandQ)) : ?>
```

I am getting error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in
```

Kindly suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Just add that to the loop.  `while ($cat_id != '' && $brand = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlOnlyCatBrands))`   Id say to use `!empty($cat_id)` because you don't want `null` or `0` or `false` either, but yea whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code structure:

```
<?php if ($cat_id != ''): ?>
    <?php while ($brand = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlOnlyCatBrands)) : ?>
    <input type="radio" name="brand" value="..."> ...<br>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php elseif ($cat_id == ''): ?>
    <?php while ($brand = mysqli_fetch_assoc($brandQ)) : ?>
    <input type="radio" name="brand" value="..."> ...<br>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Or you can make it simpler, just look what the main different for your code. So, you don't need to rewrite what was you done.

```
<?php $sql = $cat_id != '' ? $sqlOnlyCatBrands : $brandQ; ?>
<?php while ($brand = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)): ?>
    <input type="radio" name="brand" value="..."> ...<br>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: you  have to do <?php endwhile; ?> before <?php elseif ($cat_id == ''): ?>

Comment: Yes, I have do that. Please check my answer again.